# Logstash Create and Access Array

Tags: logstash

I want to create an array in the logstash config file that is for devices and then access the array value by for a new field that I am creating. example:

```
filter {
     array_devicetype => ["Cisco ASA", "Cisco 3750"]
     mutate {
            add_field => { "Device Type" => "%{array_devicetype[0]}"
     }
}
```

Yet, no luck. Can someone help me out with this? Thanks.

Comment: Do the answer have solved your problem?If not please specific more detail. Otherwise, please consider mark it as accepted answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If there is no any filter plugin can help you, you can try to use ruby and then do it yourself.
For example

```
filter {
    ruby {
            code => "
                    event['array_devicetype'] = ['Cisco ASA', 'Cisco 3750']
                    event['Device Type'] = event['array_devicetype'][0]
            "
    }
}
```

Use this filter can do what you want. FYI.

Comment: Great, thank you! So with ruby I wouldn't need to use the mutate features?

Comment: Another thing that came to mind. Can I have multiple ruby {} throughout the filter section? Can I reference or access variables created in these different ruby areas?

Comment: You can have multiple ruby{} plugin. I haven't try whether you can access local variable create in different ruby area. But, if the variable is in event. You can use it. Because the event is the global variable.