# How to add Elastic Search host name and port as parameter in Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I tried to use the host name and port for Elastic Search as parameter in Logstash output and got the following error.

> Pipeline aborted due to error LogStash::ConfigurationError: Host '%{my_es}' 
>   was specified, but is not valid! Use either a full URL or a hostname:port string

I got the error after the following command:

```
output { 
    stdout {
       codec => rubydebug { metadata => true }
    } 
    elasticsearch { 
       hosts => "%{my_es}" 
       index => "%{my_ind}" 
       document_id => "%{rwrDate}"
    }
}
```

I tried to use **%{my_es}** as parameter for the hostname.

If I use the hard coded value **hosts => ["100.100.100.100:9200"]** all work fine.

```
output { 
     stdout {
        codec => rubydebug { metadata => true }
     }
     elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"] 
        index => "%{my_ind}" 
        document_id => "%{rwrDate}"
     }
}
```

Below is the code example

```
while read line
do
echo $line | ESADDR=echo ${ESHOST} IND_NAME=echo ${PRODUCT}_${KPI} | cut -d" " -f1 | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin {} }   
filter {
    grok { match => {"message" => "%{DATE:rwrDate},%{NUMBER:rwrRate:float}"}} 
    date {match => ["rwrDate","d/M/yyyy"] locale=> "en" target => "rwrDate"} 
    environment { add_metadata_from_env => { "myes" => "ESADDR" } add_field => {"my_es" => "%{[@metadata][myes]}"} } 
    environment { add_metadata_from_env => { "ind" => "IND_NAME" } add_field => {"my_ind" => "%{[@metadata][ind]}"} } 
    mutate {remove_field => ["timestamp"]}
} 
output { 
    stdout {codec => rubydebug { metadata => true }} 
    elasticsearch { hosts => "%{my_es}" index => "%{my_ind}" document_id => "%{rwrDate}"}
}' 
done < $file
```

Comment: Try `ruby` filter. See: filter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954942/logstash-create-and-access-array

Comment: Your "hosts" param uses the value "%{my_es}" when that variable is not set.  Try adding a stdout{} output stanza, including the metadata, which might show you what logstash is seeing.  On a quick glance, I would guess you need to export the variables.

Comment: Your "while" loop and unix pre-processing is probably unnessessary.  Why not let logstash do all that work?

Comment: Hi Yuri, Could you please advise how can I initialize array in Ruby filter? hosts => ["100.100.100.100:9200"] is array type. So If I want to use hosts dynamically, I need to add array too.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using environment variables substitution from shell ?
Like this:

```
export ES_HOST1=10.192.210.100:9200

bin/logstash --path.settings=/etc/logstash -e 'output { elasticsearch { hosts => ["'$ES_HOST1'"] }}'
```

~
Possible duplicate :
[Environment Variable replacement in Logstash when running as a service in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064309/environment-variable-replacement-in-logstash-when-running-as-a-service-in-ubuntu)